# How can I remove gradients from Elementary theme?

Tags: elementary-theme

I really don't like the gradients in the Elementary theme and I was wondering if there is a way to remove them from applications like Nautilus-Elementary, Postler, Dexter, etc. I've tried commenting out the `Apps/[Application].rc` in `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` but it doesn't work. It still leaves the gradients in their place.

I'm a big fan of the other controls in the theme: the scroll bar, the way it borders gedit and the buttons, and I'd like to keep these features, but I don't like the way it styles its windows.

**EDIT:** The gradients I'm talking about are the ones at the top of the window.

Some examples:

Nautilus-Elementary:
[image]

Postler:
[image]

Rhythmbbox:
[image]

Transmission:
[image]

I'd like to create a sort of matte look, similar to this, which was done using Orta:

Nautilus-Elementary:
[image]

Postler:
[image]

Rhythmbox:
[image]

Transmission:
[image]

I'd like a flat color, preferably without the line separating the top part of the application with the bottom.

Comment: What gradients are you referring to? There are several gradients used in the theme( titlebar/menu/toolbar/buttons/..?) if you post an image and point to the specific place you are looking to change we can help.  Also, you can drop by at IRC channel #elementary on irc.freenode.net , if we are around, we could probably help you with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you are looking for is line 410 in the gtkrc file, under the section

> style "murrine-toolbar" =
>   "murrine-default"

starts with: gradient_shades 
You need to edit the gradient shade values to what you require.
1.0 is normal color, lesser than 1.0 is darker and greater than 1.0 is lighter shade.

If you want it flat you can set everything to 1.0 and it would look like :

> ```
>   gradient_shades             = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0}
> ```